# Spark UDF has a runtime crash

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have this code:

```
package com.whatever.etl

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

object UdfUtils extends Serializable {

  def getKilometersImplx(binCode: Long): Float = {
    import scala.util.Try
    Try((binCode & 0x7fffff).toFloat).toOption.getOrElse(-1f)
  }
  val getKilometers: UserDefinedFunction = udf(getKilometersImplx _) // <<<< line 14

//  val getKilometers: UserDefinedFunction = udf {(binCode: Long) =>
//    import scala.util.Try
//    Try((binCode & 0x7fffff).toFloat).toOption.getOrElse(-1f)
//  }

}
```

and I try to unit test the implementation to check this works:

```
package com.whatever.test

import com.whatever.etl.UdfUtils
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuiteLike

class UDFTest extends AnyFunSuiteLike {
  test("test getKilometers Implementation") {
    val tc: Seq[(Long, Float)] = Seq((0x800000L, 0.0f), (0xffffffL, 0x7fffff.toFloat), (0x800001L, 1.0f))
    tc.foreach { case (binCode, res) => assert(UdfUtils.getKilometersImplx(binCode) == res) }
  }
}
```

but when I run this test, I get:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.AgnosticEncoder org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.encoderForWithRowEncoderSupport(scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$TypeTag)' 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.AgnosticEncoder org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.encoderForWithRowEncoderSupport(scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$TypeTag)'
    at org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.ScalarUserDefinedFunction$.$anonfun$apply$4(UserDefinedFunction.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.ScalarUserDefinedFunction$.apply(UserDefinedFunction.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:7690)
    at com.whatever.etl.UdfUtils$.<init>(UdfUtils.scala:14)
```

I'm not sure why this occurs. I tried writing the `val getKilometers` as commented, but that didn't work either.  I'm unsure why this occurs at runtime.

Note: I have the same issue with other UDFs I am trying to write. (Subtly mentioning that there may be built-in functions but I'm not able to use these in many case so let's fix the UDF versus using a built-in.)

FYI - some build info:

```
  val sparkVersion = "3.3.0"
  val scalatestVersion = "3.2.14"
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalatestVersion % "test",
```

I can seem to sometimes break out pieces and try them in a spark-shell or Databricks Notebook, and this will run. But when I run as library jar in Databricks it fails (with `Caused by: NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.stla.whatever.etl.xxxxx$`) I'm unclear whether this is directed related to being wrapped in an object. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have some mismatches on versions, although it's 3.3.0 you are giving as an example [AgnosticEncoder](https://github.com/apache/spark/blame/7d7afb06f682c10f3900eb8adeab9fad6d49cb24/sql/api/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/AgnosticEncoder.scala#L41) was introduced in 3.4.  That function [encoderForWithRowEncoderSupport](https://github.com/apache/spark/blame/7d7afb06f682c10f3900eb8adeab9fad6d49cb24/sql/api/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/ScalaReflection.scala#L230) is introduced in 3.5.

It suggests that you are using DBR 13 or 14 - you must [match the build version](https://docs.databricks.com/en/release-notes/runtime/index.html) of OSS spark with the base runtime version of the Databricks Runtime - 3.3.0 (you should use  3.3.2) is compatible with 12.2 LTS.

As to why I mention DBR 13 (should be 3.4.x), Databricks often backports (or front runs) functionality from higher spark versions, in this case Databricks/Spark "connect" which introduces AgnosticEncoders.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ok, there is a minor mismatch in the Databricks side, but getting the unit test to work should not depend on the mismatch with running on Databricks as this unit test is run purely in IntelliJ. It's a little confusing how this mismatch comes into the build for unit testing. I'm also finding it interesting that if I run this outside of IntelliJ (with `sbt test`) I get a success, but not within. Also ran a dependency tree (for SBT) and found zero traces of spark.

Comment: at this stage you'll have to provide your code in a project with a failing test case, "zero traces of spark" is confusing given you are using udfs and show your sbt config with spark in it.  As I mention in the answer, that error message can only come from mismatched versions